Building Apache Zeppelin 0.11.1 without all interpreters
I'm trying to build tar.gz package of the Apache Zeppelin, version 0.11.1, with very minimal modules but when I check in the package I see all interpreters added and this makes tar.gz very fat.
My command
mvn package -DskipTests -Pspark-scala-2.12 -Pinclude-hadoop -Pspark-3.5 -Phadoop3  -Pbuild-distr  -pl zeppelin-interpreter,zeppelin-zengine,spark/interpreter,zeppelin-web,zeppelin-server,zeppelin-distribution,jdbc,zeppelin-plugins/notebookrepo/filesystem -am

Is there something that I'm missing ?
Thanks for help
